# Updating Rows in Table on While loop using MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong i want to update my Mysql table with 3 rows. I Selecting checkboxes and i press button then nothing happend with upadate of table. It's saving good id's to array, but update query doesen't work.

```
$s = mysql_query("SELECT data.id, data.sonda_data, data.type, odp.id, odp.sonda_data, odp.type, odp.wyniki, odp.idp FROM data,odp WHERE data.id=odp.idp");
$i=0;
$tab= array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($s))
{  
    if ( (isset($_POST['pole'.$row[3]])) && (!isset($_SESSION['security'])) )
    {
            $id = $_POST['pole'.$row[3]]; // get id from radio boxes
        $tab[i]=$id; // saving radio boxes id's to array
            $i++;   // increment array
        // array look like example 8,11,10
            if($i==3)
        { 
            while($i>=1)
            {
            mysql_query("UPDATE odp SET wyniki = (wyniki + 1) WHERE 'id=$tab[$i]'");
            $i=$i-1;
            }
            $_SESSION['security'] = true;
         }
      } 
}
```

Comment: `mysql_query("UPDATE odp SET wyniki = (wyniki + 1) WHERE id='".$tab[$i]."'");`   PS, yes, you really should convert to using mysqlI <<I at the end

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: What is the actual runtime value of the query being executed?  What does `mysql_error()` tell you?

Comment: Ok, i fixed it i change `$tab[i]=$id;` to `$tab[$i]=$id;` and in while $i>=0 . Thanks for suggestions.